# fetching data after useReducer dispatch changes local state

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, use-effect

Trying to rewrite this method using react hooks:

```
this.setState({
      isPerformingAuthAction: true
    }, () => {
      auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailAddress, password).then((value) => {
        this.closeSignInDialog(() => {
          const user = value.user;
          const displayName = user.displayName;
          const emailAddress = user.email;

          this.openSnackbar(`Signed in as ${displayName || emailAddress}`);
        });
      }).catch((reason) => {
        const code = reason.code;
        const message = reason.message;

        switch (code) {
          case 'auth/invalid-email':
          case 'auth/user-disabled':
          case 'auth/user-not-found':
          case 'auth/wrong-password':
            this.openSnackbar(message);
            return;

          default:
            this.openSnackbar(message);
            return;
        }
      }).finally(() => {
        this.setState({
          isPerformingAuthAction: false
        });
      });
    });
```

isPerformingAuthAction is a component property that disables buttons while performing various actions.

`<Button disabled={state.isPerformingAuthAction} ... />`

The Problem: I am using useReducer to manage local state and isPerformingAuthAction is a property of the reducerState. useReducer doesn't return a promise, so I can't do this:

```
dispatch({type:"isPerformingAuthAction", payload: true}).then(auth.stuff)
```

I thought about using useState instead, but it doesn't have a call back like this.setState with classes does.

I have been trying to wrap my head around some of the useEffect ways around fetching data and async. I am pretty confused about it, but I think I could have "isPerformingAuthAction" or the state from the reducer as a dependency and have useEffect update the component when it changes but the "isPerformingAuthAction" property changes for other reasons as well, not wtih just `auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailAddress, password)`, but signUp, signOut and a few others.

So when "isPerformingAuthAction" changes to true, it disables buttons so the user is forced to wait for the response from the server. I want to make sure those buttons are disabled (state updated/component re-rendered with greyed-out buttons) before I call the auth.whatever.

Comment: Have you tried writing this without hooks and just a normal class based component?

Comment: The code that I am referencing is a class component already. I am trying to refactor using hooks just for fun/practice/to learn. This may be above my skill level...